# Header/ Title is not updating between two navigators (react navigation 5)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have two navigator stacks. After sign up I switch from guest navigation to logged navigation.
But the the header remains the same as that of guest navigation. I have changed the header in logged navigation which does not get updated.

This is my guest navigation:

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Register"
                component={Register}
                options={{ title: this.registerTitle(), headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 
  'center' }, 
            
              }}
              />        
              <Stack.Screen
                name="SignUp"
                component={SignUp}
                options={{ title: this.registerTitle(), headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 
  'center' }, 
          
              }}
           
              />  
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

And this is my logged navigator:

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true} >
            <Stack.Navigator
            >
              <Stack.Screen 
                  name='SideMenu'
                  component={SideMenu}
                  options={({ navigation }) => ({ 
                     title: this.createTitle(), 
                     headerLeft: () => (
                       <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => 

navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
                             <Image style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} source={. 
require('../../assets/images/menu-icon.png')} />
    

                  </TouchableOpacity>)
                       })}
            />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```